# How to make an input width relate to label width?

Tags: css, css-float

I have a `label` and an `input` side by side in a 540px wide `div`. the `label` contains a domain name, say: http://domain.tld/ and the `input` will have the URL slug typed into it. The problem is that the domain name can change (and will change) depending of user so that means the `label`'s width will also change causing the `input` either to be too little in width or too big in width. Which in first case will result in ugly design and in the second case result in a broken float.

Does anyone have any tricks or tips for me on this? Or do I have to ninja-javascript this thing? All help is appreciated.

Comment: Downvoting without any reason that I could tell is uncalled for, don't you think?

Comment: I do want to show the total URL, I want the input width to change depending of the label. I was pretty obvious in the description as far as I can tell. Consider this as a solution theory (input's width - label's width = input width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I think I understand what you want ia for the inputs to always be flush? If so you can do this by putting then in a list or with divs but set the parent element `position` to `relative` and then the child element which is the input get its position to `absolute` and give it a position of `absolute` and set the `top` to 0 and the `right` to 0

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uVSRX/

**CSS**

```
.example { width: 340px;}

li { position: relative;} 

input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="example">
<ul>
    <li><label>Short</label><input type="text"/></li>
    <li><label>Looooooong</label><input type="text"/></li>
</ul>
```

*PS: You probably got down voted because you didn't provide any code :(*

Comment: Interesting. I already fixed it with javascript tho':

`var postSlugLabel = $('label.post-slug'); var postSlugInput = $('input.post-slug'); var postSlugInputWidth = Math.ceil(520 - postSlugLabel.width()); $('input.post-slug').css({'width': + postSlugInputWidth + 'px'});` That being said, SO does not require any code to be provided with the question and since it's such a tiny thing why would I even put a few lines of broken CSS here, right?

Comment: @AskoFoe, I know haha just some people.